# qgis-grass-plugin7 problem updating 2.18.12 ->2.18.13 (win10-linux)

Tags: qgis-grass-plugin

after updating qgis to  2.18.13 version (and GRASS from 7.2.1 to 7.2.2) via OSGeo4W advanced setup on win10 (and via repository on linux mint 18.1) the qgis-grass-plugin7 has disappeared from the list of available plugins.

This is the processing->options->programs:[image]

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Try to downgrade GRASS to 7.2.1 in the OSGEO4W advanced setup. Maybe related: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17202

Comment: Thanks, Your advice has solved the problem well on windows 10. Unfortunately I have not been able to downgrade it on Linux with synaptic because there is no version 7.2.1 available.

Comment: GRASS 7.2.1 is available on the ubuntugis stable ppa, but that requires GDAL 2.1.3, while QGIS expects GDAL 2.2.1. So no chance to get it running before QGIS 2.18.14 is released. You might switch to the QGIS debian repo (with a full remove, purge etc), but that returns you to GDAL 1.11.3 and GRASS 7.0.3

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying this point of the problem. I think I'll wait for  the next point release of qgis.

Comment: Should be fixed with QGIS 2.18.14 within the next weeks. As a general rule, don't upgrade GRASS until the next QGIS point release has been released.