# Missing Grass Toolbox plugin running QGIS 2.18.13

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-2.18, qgis-grass-plugin

I am running QGIS 2.18.13 with Grass 7.2.2[1? ... can't remember which number was shown ... see comments below] installed via the OSGEO4W installer on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 (64bit).

(I have double checked within the OSGEO4W "advanced install" directory that the "qgis-grass-plugin7" and qgis-grass-plugin-common" are installed as for version 2.18.13-1)

The Grass Plugin/Toolbox is no longer in the Plugins Manager.

This plugin/toolbox was very handily available in recent versions but seems to have vanished though I am not sure with which update.

Is the plugin/toolbox still available?

How do I re enable it?

Comment: Can you see if the answer from a similar question is helpful in your case? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214181/1297

Comment: sorry, deleted last comment which I was still drafting (accidentally clicked send)

Comment: Cheers for suggestion ... re the first answer in that post, it seems that reverting to ~grass 7.2.1 (from 7.2.2) seems to have worked ... it is now present in the plugins manager ... will test it for a bit and return.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256666/qgis-grass-plugin7-problem-updating-2-18-12-2-18-13-win10-linux . Should be fixed with QGIS 2.18.14 within the next weeks.